# Replacing Pandas Dataframe output from NoneType to 0

Tags: sql, pandas

Output of a SQL query that I am storing in a dataframe is of `NoneType`.

How could I replace this to `0`

```
db_conn.execute(f"""select count (*) from table""")
output = db_conn.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: something like `df.astype('str').replace('None','interesting')` or for a specific column like `df.col.astype('str').replace('None','interesting')` should work, else please post some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use  replace() if none is a string

```
df.replace('None', 0)
```

but for NaN you can try `fillna`

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```